# Slick2d | Shooting with same speed

Tags: java, slick2d

### The problem:

I succesfully implemented a shooting mechanism into my little game, but there is a problem. 
 The speed of the bullets are faster if my cursor is further from the player, and slower if the cursor is closer to the player.

So my question is: *How can I make the bullets always go with the same speed?*

**Links:**

> [***The game (finished)***](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhvf5vbqj25sgyw/game.jar)

**The code (from Shot.java):**

```
public Shot(World world, Camera camera, float x, float y, int width, int height, Color color, float targetX, float targetY) {
    super(world, camera, x, y, width, height, color);

    this.targetX = targetX;
    this.targetY = targetY;

    dx = targetX - x;
    dy = targetY - y;
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillOval(x - camera.getX(), y - camera.getY(), width, height);
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) {
    x += dx * delta * .005f;
    y += dy * delta * .005f;
}
```

**I did it! Here is my solution (Thanks to *Axis* for help):**

```
float dx, dy;
Vector2f vector;

public Shot(World world, Camera camera, float x, float y, float targetX, float targetY, int width, int height, Color color) {
    super(world, camera, x, y, width, height, color);

    dx = targetX - x;
    dy = targetY - y;

    vector = new Vector2f(dx, dy).normalise();
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillOval(x - camera.getX(), y - camera.getY(), width, height);
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) {
    x += vector.getX() * delta * 0.8f;
    y += vector.getY() * delta * 0.8f;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would suggest switching to a vector class instead of splitting everything up into x and y. It will save you a lot of time in the long run.

All you need to do is change

```
public Shot(World world, Camera camera, Vector2 pos, int width, int height, Color color, Vector2 target) {
    super(world, camera, pos, width, height, color);
    this.target = target

    //dx = targetX - x; get rid of this
    //dy = targetY - y; and this

//add a vector called direction

this.direction = (target - pos).Normalize();
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) {

pos += direction * delta * bulletSpeed;
}
```

Comment: Well, I have got some problems... The Slick2d has a Vector2f class. But this is not allows operations with the vector. So i cant do this: direction = (target - pos).normalize();

Comment: do direction = target.sub(pos).normalize();

Comment: And what about this line: pos += direction * delta * bulletSpeed; ?

Comment: pos.add(direction.scale(delta * bulletSpeed));

Comment: Everything seems good, but when i shoot, the bullet is created, but then the player moves with the shots. Im really confused now.

Comment: Update the link to your source with your new code and I will take a look at what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
public Shot(World world, Camera camera, float x, float y, int width, int height, Color color, float             targetX, float targetY) {
    super(world, camera, x, y, width, height, color);
    this.targetX = targetX;
    this.targetY = targetY;

    dx = targetX - x;
    dy = targetY - y;
}
```

Your bullets speed is dependent on the distance from the target. Make it a constant value.

Comment: But if i set it something like dx = 100 and dy = 100, then it will always add 100 to the x and y. And becouse of this, the bullet will contantly go to one direction. (actually to the bottom right)

Comment: @HUNeater just normalize the vector

Comment: Yes so if you make dx = -100 it will go to the left :)

Comment: You can use `if (target > x) dx = 1; if (target < x) dx = -1;`

Comment: @phcoding And what about the dy? It seems different